# Variable-heigth col-sm-4 divs on bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

In my page I have three columns and many rows to show the following elements

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<img src="<?php echo $myURL; ?>" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail">
<p class="lead"><?php echo $mytext; ?></p>
</div>
```

The display is perfect when all the $mytext are the same size (number of lines). However, if in a row elements A and B have say 2 lines of $mytext and the element C has 3 lines, the element C on the next row won't be displayed.

How can I prevent this? Ideally, the row height should be the highest of the height of the three elements in the row.

**EDIT:** If you go to http://bit.ly/1HfHiqC and reduce the width of the window, you will see what I am talking about.

Comment: Do you have any example code, or a link to your website. What do you mean by, it is not displayed, is it falling into a new row or is it totally disappearing?

Comment: Oh that is the problem, well to tell you the solution, are you generating the code with a loop or are you adding it block by block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are generating the content with a loop, lets say like this

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
  echo '<div class="col-sm-4">';
  ...
}
```

then you need to set a `counter` to add an clearfix class to every `col-n * x = 12` DIV, to clear the floats. In you example you have `n = 4` and that means you have to clear it on every 3rd iteration. To sum it up, whenerver your `row` is full, and the next row begins with a new set of cols, you have to add a class to the first div in that row.

```
$clearfix = 0;
foreach ($posts as $post) {
  if ($clearfix % 3 == 0) { $clear_class = "clearfix"; } else { $clearfix = ""; }
  echo '<div class="col-sm-4 '.$clear_class.'">';
...
  $clearfix++;
}
```

And in your css you'd add the following

```
.clearfix { clear: both; }
```

That should solve your problem.